# Finding .txt fIle using Java ( new to S.O.)

Tags: io, bufferedreader, filereader, ioexception

I'm a beginner when it comes to coding and i would appreciate help with my code that is attempting to find a text file (info.txt) which exists on my computer. It should then print out the text in that file. This is what I have so far, but only to get the error that the file is not found...

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class demo1 {
    static String filename = ("info.txt");
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{
        FileReader from = new FileReader (fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
        String currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine ()) != null){
            System.out.println(currentLine);
    }
  }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any input and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It doesn't look like that will compile. Did you check the error message.

Comment: where is your public static void main

Comment: It does compile actually, it's not until I run it that I get the FileNotFoundException

Comment: `br.readLines()` Isn't a method of buffered reader, so what you have pasted does not compile. You need the file to be in the directory you are running it from. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: That was a typo on my part, that while loop should read.  while ((currentLine = br.readLine ()) != null){

Comment: Now you have to fix your path. The `FileReader` is looking in your current directory for the file. Put the file there, run the program from the directory with the file, or use the complete path to the file.

Comment: So if the path to that file is different depending on the computer I use, will that affect the FileReader's ability to locate the file? I'll have to specify the path each time?

Comment: To open a file, you have to specify the file. Are you supplying "info.txt"? If so you should use it as a resource, and create a jar file.